# Error term in the Euclidean Weyl law

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, laplacian

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ be an open bounded set with smooth boundary. The Laplacian on $\Omega$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions has discrete spectrum $\lambda_1\le \lambda_2\le \ldots$ that accumulates at $+\infty$. Let $N(\lambda)=\#\{k\mid \lambda_k\le \lambda\}$ be the counting function. It is well known that it holds
$$
{N(\lambda)} = \lambda^{n/2}|\Omega|\omega_n + O(\lambda^{\frac{n-1}2}),
$$
where $|\Omega|$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\Omega$ and $\omega_n$ is the measure of the n-dimensional unit ball.

I am looking for references on the dependency of the big-O in the above formula w.r.t. $\Omega$. The best that I could find is in [1] (see also Theorem 16.1 in [2]), from which one obtains:
$$
{N(\lambda)} = \lambda^{n/2}|\Omega|\omega_n + |\Omega|O(\lambda^{\frac{n-1}2}),
$$
where, for any compact $K$, the big-O is uniform on $\Omega\subset K$.
However, my intuition (fuelled by the Weyl conjecture) would ask for something like
$$
{N(\lambda)} = \lambda^{n/2}|\Omega|\omega_n + |\Omega|^{\frac{\textbf{n-1}}{\textbf{n}}}O(\lambda^{\frac{n-1}2}),
$$
with the same kind of uniformity on the big-O.

Does anyone know of results of this type?

[1]: L. Hörmander, *The spectral function of an elliptic operator*, 1954.

[2]: M.A. Shubin, S.I. Andersson, _ Pseudodifferential operators and spectral theory_, 1987.

Comment: Your desired version seems weaker than the one you quote, so would be a consequence of that.

Comment: [100 Years of Weyl's Law](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.03963.pdf) is a nice survey by Ivrii that may be of interest to you.